# Include Prefix.pch in the bridging header?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Having a project that uses a `Prefix.pch` file to import some commonly used frameworks, for example:

```
// Prefix.pch
@import UIKit;
```

When a objective-c header that uses the included prefix frameworks is added to the bridging header compilation fails by not finding the classes imported by `Prefix.pch`:

```
// Bridging-Header.h
// UIKit will not be found and will cause errors
#import "FileThatUsesUIKit.h"
```

So far the cleanest solution found is to also include the `Prefix.pch` file before the rest of the `include`s, so that definitions in the prefix are available just like it is expected:

```
// Bridging-Header.h
#import "Prefix.pch"
#import "FileThatUsesUIKit.h"
```

Alternatively the specific framework can be imported into the `Bridging-Header.h` file directly, but that involves keeping on par the definitions between both the prefix file and the bridging header:

```
// Bridging-Header.h
@import UIKit;
#import "FileThatUsesUIKit.h"
```

Is importing the `Prefix.pch` file into the `Bridging-Header.h` file the correct approach? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: I could be wrong but I filed a bug report months ago with Apple about something similar. I had classes like PHPChangeObserver and others that would not get imported properly. They message me back for the first time 3 months later (last week) saying the latest Xcode beta might have fixed the problem. Might be worth checking this out and seeing if it fixes yours too: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

Comment: See if it works with 7.2